# Pyinstaller EXE of Tkinter Bootstrap Does not execute function to download data from Yfinance

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have made a small programme to download stock data from Yfinance with Tkinter Bootstrap and while the programme works fine from pycharm when i run it,it doesnt operate the download data function when i create an Exe with pyistaller, wheather the Exe is one directory or one file..Another major problem is that it builds into the Exe all exisiting dependancies in Pycharm like Matplotliv,Kiwi etc completely irrelevant to the Tkinter programme creating a 100 mb exe file!!.Can anyone provide a solution to these problems?
Thanks in advance!

This is the download function connected to a button that executes the download.I suspect the problem is in the directories but i have the files symbols,csv and datasets in the exact paths and the Executable file starts, prints and executes every butoon exept it doesnt download the data when the download button is clicked.

```
def on_download() :
    try:
       val = st_date.get()
       date_format = '%Y,%m,%d'
       start = datetime.strptime(val, date_format)
    except:
       lbl3 = ttk.Label(root, text="Wrong Format:Enter Correct!", bootstyle="Danger",
                     font=('Helvetica', 14))
       lbl3.place(x=15, y=220, width=300.0, height=30.0)

    with open(r'C:\zPythonFilesDir\yfinance\symbols.csv') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        for symbol in lines:
            #print(symbol)
            data = yf.download(symbol,start,end)
            data.to_csv(r'C:\zPythonFilesDir\yfinance\datasets\{}.csv'.format(symbol))
            #print('onkey donkey')
        Messagebox.show_info('Download Completed!','Message')
        lbl4.config(text = f' Last Symbol Data Downloaded Is : {symbol}')
```

i tried work around the directories but without success and i am puzzeled because in other tkinter applications i have done the directories work fine when i place the files in the exact path!